# Select the last elements using CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way of targeting the last X elements in a group using ONLY `CSS` (assuming we don't know how many elements there are)?

Example - target the last 3 elements in a `ul`:

```
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
  ...
  <li>Element X-2</li>
  <li>Element X-1</li>
  <li>Element X</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`:nth-last-child(N)` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-last-child):

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    /* ... */
}
```

[See this demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/f9rcc/)

Answer (score 4):

This will apply style for the last 3 elements.
<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4e9Ee/)</kbd>

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+3)
{
    ....
}
```

**Support**

```
Feature        Chrome   Firefox    (Gecko)    IE    Opera   Safari
Basic support   4.0     3.5        (1.9.1)    9.0   9.5   3.2
```

Comment: I did not add this as duplicate answer, i saw Linus added 3 selectors for nth-last-child, i thought it can be combined to one like the one above.

Comment: Caveat: no support in IE 8 and older; polyfills available, e.g. http://selectivizr.com/.

Comment: @Jukka Very important! Thx for your help.